# How to recover when one svn commit accidentally deletes contents from a previous commit?

Tags: svn, latex

I accidentally initiated a commit without reloading my file after some earlier commit which replaced the changes of the earlier commit by the previous texts. As I was working on a different part of the code svn did not reported any conflict. But it was a complete mess. How can I recover from this problem without doing it manually? To recover I need to retain my current changes as well as to restore the previous changes on other part of the program which I accidentally deleted by my commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to fix overwriting changes within a single file, is to manually invoke a 3-way merge tool.

Assume you have revision 1 which you based your changes from. Revision 3 is what you committed with your changes. Unfortunately, revision 2 happened in between and those changes got removed by revision 3.

So, invoke a 3-way merge tool with "base" set to revision 1's file, and the file from revisions 2 and 3 as the other two revisions.

You can get the required files using the `svn cat` command.

Save the result and commit as revision 4 to correct things.

In the future, always close your editor before you commit, and always do an update before you commit as well as before starting your work.

Comment: I ended up doing this. I thought my editor dynamically loads the changes on disk, as most of the files on mac dynamically changes unlike windows.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have accidentally deleted the files at revision 100. In your working copy update to revision 99. `svn up -r 99` . This will bring all the deleted files in your working copy. Take a backup of the files you deleted. Now update the working copy to the latest revision `svn up`. and copy the files from backup to the working copy, `svn add` and `svn commit`.